# objective c cocoa delegates, conceptual

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I am going to have several uiimageview interactive sulasses that need a delegate. when each one of them is touched, the view controller must respond by changing something.

Is it good common practice to have one method , that is the delegate method get called by all of the uiimageview subclass instances?

The delegate will be the view controller.

Overall, is that good practice?

Comment: If you're asking if it's better to have one method that gets called as opposed to one for each subclass, then yes, certainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is better. This one will be a good option `- (void)imageViewTouched:(UIImageView *)sender`

You should follow DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself) principle and eliminate code duplcication in your app. So you should have separate methods if they have separate logic. You should have one method if the same type of logic executed for various senders.

Comment: I updated my answer a little bit since using of one method is not always the case :)

Comment: You can still have one method with conditional logic if you pass it some reference or info about the object it is delegating for. NSNotification has this ability with the optional user info dictionary parameter.

Comment: As I mentioned it is possible to have one or several methods and it is all depends on the case. There is no clear answer "implement everything in X amount of methods". The main goal is to keep your code logical and eliminate code duplication. It is not about what ObjC allows or not allows to do and what facilities it provides. It is about base coding approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Pass in the sender so you can make decisions based on who sent you the message (like `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`), and you have a good implementation of the delegation pattern.